# Running partition specific query in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am working on spark streaming application, where I partition the data as per a certain ID in the data.

```
For eg: partition 0-> contains all data with id 100
partition 1 -> contains all data with id 102
```

Next I want to execute query on whole dataframe for final result. But my query is specific to each partition.

```
For eg: I need to run 
select(col1 * 4) in case of partiton 0 
while 
select(col1 * 10) in case of parition 1.
```

I have looked into documentation but didnt find any clue. One solution i have is to create different RDDs/ Dataframe for different id in data. But that is not scalable in my case. 
Any suggestion how to run query on dataframe where query can be specific to each partition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not couple your business logic with Spark's way of partitioning your data (you won't be able to repartition your data if required). I would suggest to add an artificial column in your DataFrame that equals with the partitionId value.

In any case, you can always do

`df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ case (partId, iter: Iterable[Row]) => ...}`

See also the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).